# IDC script offsets

Tags: ida, idc

I'm new to IDC scripts and would like some help at trying to apply and offset to a binary I have in loaded in IDA. Sorry not sure if my terminology is correct but I have a reference in my file "fp" that is the memory offset and is shown like

```
ld24    fp, #0x808000
```

all of the references in the file show something like,

```
lduh    R0, @(-0x2700, fp)
```

which make it difficult to link the memory addresses. If I press Ctrl-R I can correct these offsets in the file line by line but I would like a script that can do the whole file in one go if possible.
[image]

this gives me what I am looking for

```
lduh    R0, @((unk_805900 - unk_808000), fp)
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 0):

After doing the necessary operation in IDA, use File > Produce file > Dump database to IDC and look for operations with the corresponding address. Most likely it will be something like `op_offset()`.

Comment: Hi Igor, thank you for the reply. I've tried this but there are no references to the offset in the IDC file that is generated?